# How to make Spring boot CSV message converter display CSV inline and not download when using a browser

Tags: spring-boot, csv, content-negotiation

I created a spring starter project in eclipse . Most of the code was from this link https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/csv-msg-converter.html.

I added content negotiation configuration to accept headers, path extension and parameters. It works great from postman.

But when I try in a browser http://localhost:8080/employeelist.csv. In all the cases CSV is getting downloaded in a file. I want it displayed inline on the browser. I tried to set content disposition as inline in Request mapping, http output message header but still CSV is always getting downloaded.

What should I be doing to get csv displayed inline? I had previously successfully displayed CSV inline in a browser by having separate request mapping method for CSV and make the method return void and accept httpservletresponse as parameter. But I want to use content negotiation and a single method for all formats - XML, CSV, json. Whatever format selected should be displayed inline in the browser.

Is that possible ?

Thanks a lot for your time.

**Update : added portions of code which were edited**

```
package ti.projects;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

@EnableWebMvc

@Configuration

@ComponentScan("ti.projects")

public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override

       public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

              converters.add(new CsvHttpMessageConverter<>());

       }

       public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

       configurer.favorPathExtension(true).favorParameter(true).parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)

                           .useJaf(false).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

                           .mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv"));

       }

}

package ti.projects;



import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;



import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;



@Controller

public class ExampleController {



    @RequestMapping(

              value = "/newEmployee",

              consumes = "text/csv",

              produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,

              method = RequestMethod.POST)

    @ResponseBody

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    public String handleRequest (@RequestBody EmployeeList employeeList) {

        System.out.printf("In handleRequest method, employeeList: %s%n", employeeList.getList());

        String s = String.format("size: " + employeeList.getList().size());

        System.out.println(s);

        return s;

    }



    @RequestMapping(

              value = "/employeeList",

              produces = {"text/csv", "application/json"},

              method = RequestMethod.GET

             )

    @ResponseBody

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    public EmployeeList handleRequest2 () {

        List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(

                  new Employee("1", "Tina", "111-111-1111"),

                  new Employee("2", "John", "222-222-2222")

        );

        EmployeeList employeeList = new EmployeeList();

        employeeList.setList(list);

        return employeeList;

    }

}
package ti.projects;



import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication

public class ContentNegotiationApplication {



       public static void main(String[] args) {

              SpringApplication.run(ContentNegotiationApplication.class, args);

       }



}
```

Comment: We might want to see actual details, you might have changed/missed a few things

Comment: Shailesh, I have pasted below the changes I made to the code downloaded from https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/csv-msg-converter.html

Comment: I think it is browser rendering behavior, also I guess you want to remove companay name from package names

Comment: Thanks Shailesh. So is there we can do about the browser rendering behavior?

Comment: Ideally, the UI component calling your service should render it, or you can send string and set produces to text/html, I am not aware of another way. might be someone else can help

Comment: Thank you. I understand.

Answer (score 1):

The browser (should) use the provided mime type to decide how to display or process the response. What should work is using a MIME of text/plain to let the browser  render the received content as text.

You can set the MIME type of your response in your spring Controller like this:

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String renderCsv() {...}
```

If you want to offer different MIME types with one method you have three options:

1. Use query parameter (e.g. `...?contentType=json`)
2. Use path parameter (e.g.`.../{contentType}`)
3. Use accept header of client (preferably?)

You can register different MessageConverter for each contentType and configure a [ContentNegotiationConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html) to automatically choose the correct converter depending on given MIME type and your preferences.

I'll try to attach an example tonight.

Comment: Hi Fabian, I will try. I want to use the same getMapping for all formats - CSV, JSON & XML. Having MIME type as MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE will it work for all ?

Comment: Hi Fabian, I did add a message converter just for CSV. XML and json worked without any additional code except XML format needed pom dependency. CSV was getting downloaded .  I was trying to display CSV inline on the browser.  Are you saying we need converters for XML and json too?

Comment: Not sure about XML but Json converter is provided by default. But Spring decides whch MessageConverter to use depending on the contentType information which can be set on the MesageConverter. You then have the mentioned three ways to provide this information to Spring using the ContentNegotiationConfigurer.

Comment: but csv is getting downloaded?

Comment: That your browser downloads the csv is a Browser setting (you can configure how to handle different content types, e.g. opening in Excel)
If you want to force rendering csv, json and xml in the Browser the text/plain content  type should work (even though it's not "correct" type). I understood that this worked for you ?

To use only one method to provide all three types using  MessageConverters, you could define a ContentNegotiationConfigurer. See my answer for the options. Hope I could clarify?

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I will look into the browser setting. I am still figuring out how to work with text/plain and contentnegotiationconfigurer.